# Use of proper symbols (= or ~) with leaflet package

Tags: javascript, r, leaflet

I have seen two different formats used with popups in the leaflet package. For a single popup attached to a single marker, functions are called using "=" to assign variable values. (see https://rstudio.github.io/leaflet/popups.html). For a plot of multiple data values, I see both "=" and "= ~" used to assign values to variables. (see [Change color of leaflet marker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32940617/change-color-of-leaflet-marker)). I may not be making the correct observation, but does this relate to a singular point as opposed to a multiple points, or to something else? Where would I find the rules here?

Comment: `=` and `~` are unrelated. `=` assigns to parameters; `~` invokes R's formula interface, which is used in a lot of different ways, but generally to pass variables. If you really want a useful answer, post [a MRE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610).

Comment: Understood. It is just not possible to generate a sample problem with the ~ character as I have know idea what it means, or what word to use in order to do a proper search. I thought the choice between = and ~ was a possible source to the problem I was having, but the problem was elsewhere, and it is now solved using only =. Sorry I bothered you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps, [these lines in leaflet](https://github.com/rstudio/leaflet/blob/master/R/normalize.R#L24-L51) might help explain what is happening.  In effect the `~` means to evaluate that expression with the `data` provided.  Your comment "does this relate to a singular point as opposed to a multiple points" is very close to the correct observation.  If you look again at the lines, the `doResolveFormula` is defined for `data.frame`, `list`, `map`, and `Spatial*`.

#### Explain in Code

Let's build off the [popups example](https://rstudio.github.io/leaflet/popups.html) to hopefully explain this in code.  This is the example.

```
library(leaflet)

content <- paste(sep = "<br/>",
                 "<b><a href='http://www.samurainoodle.com'>Samurai Noodle</a></b>",
                 "606 5th Ave. S",
                 "Seattle, WA 98138"
)

leaflet() %>% addTiles() %>%
  addPopups(-122.327298, 47.597131, content,
            options = popupOptions(closeButton = FALSE)
  )
```

Now, let's put the `lat`, `lng`, and content all in a `data.frame`, and **make an error** on our path to discovery.

```
content_df <- data.frame(
  lng = -122.327298,
  lat = 47.59731,
  content = content
)

leaflet() %>% addTiles() %>%
  addPopups(content_df,
            options = popupOptions(closeButton = FALSE)
  )
```

So even though there is only one data point for our content, `leaflet` does not know how to map the columns of the `data.frame` to the arguments it expects.  Here is how to help `leaflet` understand.

```
content_df <- data.frame(
  lng = -122.327298,
  lat = 47.59731,
  content = content
)

leaflet() %>% addTiles() %>%
  addPopups(
    lng = ~lng,
    lat = ~lat,
    popup = ~content,
    # default data is getMapData(map)
    #  which does not contain our popup content
    data = content_df,
    options = popupOptions(closeButton = FALSE)
  )
```

#### Manually Evaluate `~`

Let's manually use `resolveFormula` to see what is happening.

```
leaflet:::resolveFormula(~content,content_df)
```

which gives us the `content` column of our `content_df`.

```
    [1] <b><a href='http://www.samurainoodle.com'>Samurai Noodle</a></b><br/>606 5th Ave. S<br/>Seattle, WA 98138
```

Outside of our mapping application, I'll add a simple contrived example to explain in one more way.

```
leaflet:::resolveFormula(~1+2,data.frame())
```

gives us `1+2`.

```
3
```

The empty `data.frame()` is necessary, so R will choose `doResolveFormula.data.frame`.  We could have also used `list()`.

#### Why It Is Important

I really hope this helps.  This is sort of an unconventional use of `~`, and I had trouble with it at first also.  However, I think it is important to understand as more and more packages outside of RStudio's are adopting this convention.