# Assigning different icons based on a factor

Tags: r, leaflet

I'm trying to plot a map of all trees located in Melbourne. 
The link to the dataset I'm using is over here - [Melbourne Urban Tree Data](https://data.melbourne.vic.gov.au/Environment/Melbourne-s-Urban-Forest-Tree-data/fp38-wiyy)

In the dataset i want to assign different icons based on the column name "Genus" which looks something like this:
[image]

Right now I'm able to get circles in the final plot:
[image]

The code that I've used so far:

```
library(leaflet)
library(dplyr)

td <- read.csv("treedata.csv", header = TRUE)
m <- leaflet(td) %>% addTiles('http://{s}.basemaps.cartocdn.com/dark_all/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', 
                              attribution='Map tiles by <a href="http://stamen.com">Stamen Design</a>, <a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/3.0">CC BY 3.0</a> &mdash; Map data &copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>')
m %>% addCircles(~Longitude, ~Latitude, popup=paste("Name:", td$CommonName), weight = 3, radius=3, 
                 color="#ffa500", stroke = TRUE, fillOpacity = 0.8)
```

Comment: You can use your own markers, you just need the `.png`s. See [here](https://rstudio.github.io/leaflet/markers.html). One question, how did you make leaflet work with so many points?

Comment: You can use the `addCircles()` function and also look at this tutorial - [http://trendct.org/2015/06/26/tutorial-how-to-put-dots-on-a-leaflet-map-with-r/]. Hope this helps.

Comment: TimSalabim, I had worked on this a while back and was able to plot a whole lot of points https://github.com/rstudio/leaflet/pull/174#issuecomment-135988304

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment from @TimSalabim, try using markers with icons. For the fun of it:

```
library(leaflet)
library(dplyr)
library(readr)
download.file("https://data.melbourne.vic.gov.au/api/views/fp38-wiyy/rows.csv?accessType=DOWNLOAD", tf <- tempfile(fileext = ".csv"))
set.seed(1)
td <- read_csv(tf) %>% 
  sample_n(500) %>% 
  mutate(Genus = factor(ifelse(Genus %in% c("Quercus", "Corymbia", "Platanus", "Ulmus", "Eucalyptus"), Genus, "other"))) 
m <- leaflet(td) %>% 
  addTiles(urlTemplate = 'http://{s}.basemaps.cartocdn.com/dark_all/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',
           attribution='Map tiles by <a href="http://stamen.com">Stamen Design</a>, <a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/3.0">CC BY 3.0</a> &mdash; Map data &copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>')
myicons <- iconList(
  Quercus = makeIcon("https://i.stack.imgur.com/okgqd.png",iconWidth = 8, iconHeight = 8),
  Corymbia = makeIcon("https://i.stack.imgur.com/nfGZT.png",iconWidth = 8, iconHeight = 8),
  Platanus = makeIcon("https://i.stack.imgur.com/J47uj.png",iconWidth = 8, iconHeight = 8),
  Ulmus = makeIcon("https://i.stack.imgur.com/idnpO.png",iconWidth = 8, iconHeight = 8),
  Eucalyptus = makeIcon("https://i.stack.imgur.com/6GzzW.png",iconWidth = 8, iconHeight = 8),
  other = makeIcon("https://i.stack.imgur.com/x0bOg.png",iconWidth = 8, iconHeight = 8)
)
m %>% addMarkers(~Longitude, ~Latitude, popup=paste("Name:", td$`Common Name`),
                 icon = ~myicons[Genus])
```

gives something like:

[image]

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: little typo: change `"oher"` in `"other"` at  `mutate(Genus = factor(ifelse(Genus %in% c("Quercus", "Corymbia", "Platanus", "Ulmus", "Eucalyptus"), Genus, "other")))`

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot guys! Almost completed this!

Comment: Great answer! I am still curious though how this will work with all data points (not only 500)?

Comment: I was just wondering if I can add colours to these icons based on the Life Expectancy column in the dataset?

Comment: @TimSalabim I'd be curious, too - chokes my (rather old) machine.

Comment: @ArvindSuryanarayana Afaik no, these are raster images; you'd have to pre-build them with different colors. Maybe you use [FontAwesome icons](http://fontawesome.io/icons/) -  here's how http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32940617/change-color-of-leaflet-marker

Comment: @lukeA got it! was thinking along the same lines. Btw, how did you manage to get these icons? From the image i uploaded?

Comment: @ArvindSuryanarayana I just used an image tool like Gimp and quickly cut them out.

Comment: @lukeA Cool! Thanks for that!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111983/discussion-between-arvind-suryanarayana-and-lukea).