# Custom markers on Shiny leaflet map

Tags: r, dictionary, icons, leaflet, customization

I need to map on Shiny leaflet map points based on their type - four types in total with the same marker of a different color.

I checked this:

https://rstudio.github.io/leaflet/markers.html

This looks like my response, but I cannot fix it :(
[Change color of leaflet marker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32940617/change-color-of-leaflet-marker)

This code was shared in the answer

```
library(dplyr)
library(leaflet)

mutate(quakes, group = cut(mag, breaks = c(0, 5, 6, Inf), labels = c("blue", 
"green", "orange"))) -> mydf

### I edit this png file and created my own marker.
### https://raw.githubusercontent.com/lvoogdt/Leaflet.awesome-
markers/master/dist/images/markers-soft.png
quakeIcons <- iconList(blue = makeIcon("/Users/jazzurro/Documents/Stack 
Overflow/blue.png", iconWidth = 24, iconHeight =32),
                   green = makeIcon("/Users/jazzurro/Documents/Stack 
Overflow/green.png", iconWidth = 24, iconHeight =32),
                   orange = makeIcon("/Users/jazzurro/Documents/Stack 
Overflow/orange.png", iconWidth = 24, iconHeight =32))


leaflet(data = mydf[1:100,]) %>% 
addTiles() %>%
addMarkers(icon = ~quakeIcons[group])
```

I basically have the same code

```
# Create our own custom icons
teamIcons <- iconList(
A = makeIcon("C:/Map/Asset 20.png", iconWidth = 18, iconHeight = 18),
B = makeIcon("C:/Map/Asset 21.png", iconWidth = 18, iconHeight = 18),
C = makeIcon("C:/Map/Asset 22.png", iconWidth = 18, iconHeight = 18),
D = makeIcon("C:/Map/Asset 23.png", iconWidth = 18, iconHeight = 18))
```

data1 <- data %>% mutate(type = factor(data$type), c("A", "B", "C", "D"))

Then I just do

```
m <- leaflet(data=data) %>%
addProviderTiles(providers$Stamen.TonerLite) %>%
addMarkers(~data1$long, ~data1$lat, icon = ~teamIcons[data1$type], popup 
state_popup)
```

Data for addMarkers is taken from another dataset - data1, not data. When I use awesome icons, it does not create problems. When I use my own icons from the directory, I have an ordinary blue marker on a map.

**Invalid subscript type 'logical'**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46313112/5292302) of [Oleksiy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7484093/oleksiy), help me a lot.

But I found two errors in the mutate function, it miss the name of the datafame to transform and, as you create `data2`, I guess that factor function have to work with `data2` dataframe.

So

```
mutate(data2,type=factor(data2$project_id),c("project1","project2"))
```

instead of

```
mutate(type=factor(data$project_id),c("project1","project2")`.
```

Answer (score 2):

Resolved personally.

```
library(leaflet)
library(dplyr)
```

Each icon was customized with numbers personally and was put into the working directory.

Then use icon_list()

```
# Create our own custom icons
icon_list <- iconList(
project1 = makeIcon("C:/Map/1.png", iconWidth = 24, iconHeight = 30),
project2 = makeIcon("C:/Map/2.png", iconWidth = 24, iconHeight = 30)
```

etc as many as you have

project1, project2 etc match the same names in the dataset column of course and in the dataset each project should have long and lat.

Then

```
data2 <- data %>% mutate(type = factor(data$project_id), c("project1", 
"project2")
```

In server, the simple code will be something like this

```
m <-  leaflet(data=data) %>% 
  addProviderTiles(providers$Stamen.TonerLite) %>%
  addMarkers(~data2$long, ~data2$lat, icon=~icon_list[data2$project_id], 
  popup = state_popup)
```

Thanks to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32940617/change-color-of-leaflet-marker)