# How to create leaflet markers colored by a numeric variable

Tags: r, maps, leaflet

I have a data frame with `latitude`, `longitude`, and a `number`. I want to add markers that are colored corresponding to these numbers. The numbers start at 1 and can be up to 100 or more.

Optimally, I would like markers with a value <= 1 to be orange, <=10 to be dark orange, <=50 to be red, and >=50 to be purple.

This seems like a simple idea, but I can't quite figure it out. I tried to use the Awesome Icons (*though I would rather not*) from the [leaflet site](https://rstudio.github.io/leaflet/markers.html) (*scroll down to the if statement in the Awesome Icon section*), but that method was actually not working for me, and all the markers were red.

```
             lat            lon            number
1       19.59917     -155.42009                 3
2       22.21065     -159.47324               120
3       22.21407     -159.59058                 7
4       24.54509      -81.70717                49
5       24.54630      -81.81060                 1
6       24.55411      -81.80333                11
```

Above is sample data. It is part of a shiny app.

Comment: You should submit your code and an extract of your data to figure how to help you...

Comment: I added sample data.

Answer (score 6):

Since there is no reproducible data, I created a sample data. First, I obtained polygon data for California and created random data points staying in California. Then, I added random numbers staying between 0 and 100. Then, I created a grouping variable called `group`, which is for coloring in icons. You want dark orange. But, seeing the CRAN manual, the color is not available for `makeAwesomeIcon()`. So I chose dark red, instead. Then, I created icons and drew a map. Since there is no reproducible data, I cannot see what you have in your hand. But I hope this demonstration gets you going.

```
library(raster)
library(sp)
library(dplyr)
library(leaflet)

usa <- getData("GADM", country = "usa", level = 1)
cal <- subset(usa, NAME_1 == "California")

foo <- as(cal, "SpatialPolygons")

set.seed(111)
mydata <- spsample(foo, n = 100, "random") %>%
          as.data.frame %>%
          mutate(number = sample.int(n = 100, replace = FALSE),
                 group = cut(number, breaks = c(0, 1, 10, 50, Inf),
                             labels = c("orange", "darkred", "red", "purple"),
                 include.lowest = TRUE)) %>%
          rename(long = x, lat = y)

icons <- awesomeIcons(icon = "whatever",
                      iconColor = "black",
                      library = "ion",
                      markerColor = mydata$group)

leaflet() %>%
addProviderTiles("OpenStreetMap.Mapnik") %>%
addAwesomeMarkers(data = mydata, ~long, ~lat, icon = icons)
```

[image]

Comment: It seems this solution is dependent on making up random data at the same time, I'm not sure how to implement this.

Comment: @Heliornis I think the answer is no. I needed to create a sample data since you did not provide any till now. Seeing your sample, you need to create a new grouping variable using `cut()` or any other similar functions that does the same job. Once you have the variable, you can handle your task.

Comment: I was also looking for an answer that didn't use awesomeIcons, which I originally specified in my question

Comment: Then you probably wanna study [**this question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32940617/change-color-of-leaflet-marker/32940862#32940862). I avoided this method because this way would give you a harder time. If you use this method, you need to have your own images in your hand whereas `addAwesomeMarkers()` allows you to have different colors in markers without any tedious work.