# Change color of Leaflet dropped pin marker

Tags: r, leaflet

I am trying to change the color of the dropped pin marker in `leaflet` in R. It appears to only come in a default color with the white dot in the middle. I have tried using `makeAwesomeIcon`, but this only allows you to select from a short list of possible `markerColor` (see this link: [Change color of leaflet marker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32940617/change-color-of-leaflet-marker)). I need to be able to use any hex color code and specifically need to use the dropped pin icon. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

This answer does what you're looking for, through the creation of a new css style for the marker https://stackoverflow.com/a/40870439/6103550